# React: Accessing context from within a Redux store

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-context

I am a seasoned Angular developer who has now decided to learn React. To this end, I am rewriting one of my web apps in React. I have been reading about replacing Redux with the Context API and the `useReducer()` hook, but in my case I don't think this would be a good idea since my state is quite large and I don't yet have the React skill to mitigate any performance problems that might arise.

So I have decided to stick with Redux.

I now have the problem that I have a context that I need to make use of in my Redux store. My `SocketProvider` looks like this:

```
export const SocketProvider = ({
                                 children,
                                 endpoint
                               }) => {
  const [socket, setSocket] = useState();
  const [connected, setConnected] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    // set socket and init
  }, [isAuthenticated]);

  return (
    <SocketContext.Provider
      value={{
        socket,
        connected
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </SocketContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

I would like to use the `socket` value from the `SocketContext` within my Redux store, like in this async action:

```
export const fetchComments = (issue: Issue): AppThunk => async dispatch => {
  try {
    dispatch(getCommentsStart())
    const comments = socket.emit('getComment', issue.comments_url) // how can I get this socket?
    dispatch(getCommentsSuccess({ issueId: issue.number, comments }))
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch(getCommentsFailure(err))
  }
}
```

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <SocketProvider endpoint={process.env.REACT_APP_API_SOCKET_ENDPOINT}>
      <Provider store={store}>
        { /* my components */}
      </Provider>
    </SocketProvider>
  );
}
```

I receive errors like this when I try to grab the socket context in my store code:

> Unhandled Rejection (Error): Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.

I can understand why this is happening, but I don't know the best way to solve it. I could keep all the thunks local to my components, or pass the context as a parameter in the async actions, but neither of these is really satisfactory.

Suggestions?

Comment: It looks like you are using class components in react not functional components, if you need to use hooks you should go with functional components

Comment: This should work, you just don't read it right, you should add some context (like how you actually reading it)

Comment: `I need to use values on the SocketProvider context in my store` What does that mean? You want to use it in reducers, action creators, selectors or middleware? What is SocketProvider? If you need values from SocketProvider then is there a way you can put those values in the redux store through dispatching actions?

Comment: @Kalhan.Toress I am in fact using functional components. I have updated my question,

Comment: @HMR I have added clarity to my question